# Printing out a SQL table in an R Sweave PDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sql-server-2008, sweave

This seems like it should be very simple but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere I look.

This seems like it has just as much chance being easier to solve using clever SQL queries as it is to use R code.

The table is being pulled into the script with this code:

```
dbhandle <- SQLConn_remote(DBName = "DATABASE", ServerName = "SERVER")
Testdf<-sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from TABLENAME
                order by FileName, Number, Category', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to print out a SQL Table on a R Sweave PDF. I'd like to do it with the following conditions:

- Printing only specific columns. This seems simple enough using `sqlQuery` but I've already created a variable in my script called `Testdf` that contains all of the table so I'd rather just subset that if I can. The reason I'm not satisfied to simply do this, is because the next condition seems beyond me in queries.
- Here's the tricky part. In the sample table I gave below, There is a list of File names that are organized by Version numbers and group `Number`s. I'd like to print the table in the .Rnw file so that there are 3 columns. The 1st column is the `FileName` column, the 2nd column is a column of all Values where `Number` == 2, and the final (3rd) column is a column of all Values where `Number` == 3.

Here's what the table looks like:

```
|  Name | Version | Category | Value |  Date  | Number |   Build   | Error |
|:-----:|:-------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|:------:|:---------:|:-----:|
| File1 | 0.01    | Time     | 123   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File1 | 0.01    | Size     | 456   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File1 | 0.01    | Final    | 789   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File2 | 0.01    | Time     | 312   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File2 | 0.01    | Size     | 645   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File2 | 0.01    | Final    | 978   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File3 | 0.01    | Time     | 741   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File3 | 0.01    | Size     | 852   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File3 | 0.01    | Final    | 963   | 1-1-12 | 1      | Iteration | None  |
| File1 | 0.02    | Time     | 369   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File1 | 0.02    | Size     | 258   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File1 | 0.02    | Final    | 147   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File2 | 0.02    | Time     | 753   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File2 | 0.02    | Size     | 498   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File2 | 0.02    | Final    | 951   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File3 | 0.02    | Time     | 753   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File3 | 0.02    | Size     | 915   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
| File3 | 0.02    | Final    | 438   | 1-1-12 | 2      | Iteration | None  |
```

Here's what I'd like it to look like:

```
|  Name | 0.01 | 0.02 |
|:-----:|:----:|:----:|
| File1 | 123  | 369  |
| File1 | 456  | 258  |
| File1 | 789  | 147  |
| File2 | 312  | 753  |
| File2 | 645  | 498  |
| File2 | 978  | 951  |
| File3 | 741  | 753  |
| File3 | 852  | 915  |
| File3 | 963  | 438  |
```

The middle and right column titles are derived from the original `Version` column. The values in the middle column are all of the entries in the `Value` column that correspond to both `0.01` in the `Version` column and `1` in the `Number` column. The values in the right column are all of the entries in the `Value` column that correspond to both `0.02` in the `Version` column and `2` in the `Number` column.

**Here's a sample database for reference and if you'd like to reproduce this using R:**

```
rw1 <- c("File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3")
rw2 <- c("0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03")
rw3 <- c("Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final")
rw4 <- c(123, 456, 789, 312, 645, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498, 951, 753, 915, 438, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498)
rw5 <- c("01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12")
rw6 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
rw7 <- c("Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release")
rw8 <- c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Cannot Connect to Database", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None")


Testdf = data.frame(rw1, rw2, rw3, rw4, rw5, rw6, rw7, rw8)
colnames(Testdf) <- c("FileName", "Version", "Category", "Value", "Date", "Number", "Build", "Error")
```

Comment: In your example table you have equal numbers of `Version`s and `Version` and `Number` correspond. In your example R data neither is true. I can kind of see how this makes sense in the first case, but I don't think it makes sense at all given the unequal numbers in the example R data.

Comment: @Ista I don't think I'm following what your saying.

Comment: I'm saying that `Testdf1` has 9 rows where `Version = 0.01` and `Number = 1`, 8 rows where `Version = 0.02` and `Number = 2`, 1 row where `Version = 0.03` and `Number = 2`, and 9 rows where `Version = 0.03` and `Number = 3`. Your original example table is much simpler: 9 rows where `Version = 0.01` and `Number = 1`, and 9 rows where `Version = 0.02` and `Number = 2`. It's not clear how to do the operation you describe on the more complicated `Testdf`.

Comment: That was an error. All iterations of versions and numbers should have 9 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The relevant variables are selected. An index column is then added to allow for the data to be `spread` without issues around duplicate indices. The data is then reshaped with `spread`, and finally the Index column removed.

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
Testdf %>%
  select(FileName, Version, Value) %>%
  group_by(FileName, Version) %>%
  mutate(Index = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(Version, Value) %>%
  select(-Index)
```

If it can always be assumed that for each FileName there will be 9 Values, one for each combination of Version and Category, then this would work:

```
Testdf %>%
    select(FileName, Category, Version, Value) %>%
    spread(Version, Value) %>%
    select(-Category)
```

If you wanted to use `data.table`, you could do:

```
setDT(Testdf)[, split(Value, Version), by = FileName]
```

If you want LaTeX output, then you could further pipe the output to `xtable::xtable`.